# How to make a foldl on the values returned by a selector in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, functional-programming, fold

Say I have some HTML elements:

```
<div>First</div>
<div>Second</div>
<div>Third</div>
```

Whose content I select via a:

```
$('div').text();
```

How can I make a "foldl" operation on the elements (iterate, accumulating a result), for example to join them using a newline?

```
$('div').text().foldl('', function(){ ... join_or_whatever ... })
```

Comment: Updated tags to include javascript, functional-programming and folding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia article on [folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29), JavaScript's Array.reduce() (for foldl) and Array.reduceRight() (for foldr) functions provide array folding.

So your specific task becomes:

```
var result = $.makeArray($('div')).reduce(function(prev,curr){ 
        return prev + '\n' + $(curr).text() 
});
```

Note that not all implementations of JavaScript support reduce and reduceRight, so see this [example implementation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_reduce.htm) if needed.

UPDATED: Since jQuery doesn't return a true array for $(selector) and some platforms do not support reduce and reduceRight on jQuery's "array-like" collection, I've updated the answer to use $.makeArray() as suggested below. Thanks to @royas for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what foldl is but

here's how you iterate and concatenate:

```
var newArray = [];
//'div' is an outer container of your inner divs
$('div').each(function(index, Element) {
    newArray.push($(this).text());
});

$('body').append(newArray.join(''));
```

Comment: You have a syntax error here... the line with `}` needs to be `});`

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you mean by "foldl", not sure...
But try this:

```
var finalStr = "";
$('div').each(function(index) {
   finalStr += $(this).text() + "<br>";
});
```

Available at: http://api.jquery.com/each/